# select a distinct attribute in sql but only for time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in SQL that has a number of columns

Date Time , user name, read id

i need to count the number of distinct read id in table but only for 10 mins intervals

for example if my table looks like this

```
1 2016/06/08 15:49:10.000 user1 5859
2 2016/06/08 15:48:39.000 user1 5859
3 **2016/06/08 15:47:53.000 user3 5859**
4 **2016/06/08 15:35:58.000 user1 5859**
```

i want it to return 2 since the in the example 1 2 and 3 are not 10 minutes apart but 3 and 4 are

for example if my table looks like this

```
1 2016/06/08 15:49:10.000 user1 5859
2 2016/06/08 15:48:39.000 user1 5859
3 **2016/06/08 15:47:53.000 user3 5859**
```

but for this it will return 1 since they are all less then 10 minutes apart

in essence i want it to count on distinct read ids but only if they are more then 10 minutes apart 
i dont mind using fixed time intervals (1:00,1:10,1:20...etc)

so i know i can do a distinct on my read id but then it is for entire table is there way to mimic a distinct but only for time intervals?

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and the new result.

Comment: done. hope it is more understandable

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is using "buckets". Below code rounds down time stamp to the nearest 10 minute interval:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test( ID INT, DT DATETIME, Username VARCHAR( 50 ), ReadID INT )
INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES(
1, '2016/06/08 15:49:10.000', 'user1', 5859 ),
( 2, '2016/06/08 15:48:39.000', 'user1', 5859 ),
( 3, '2016/06/08 15:47:53.000', 'user3', 5859 ),
( 4, '2016/06/08 15:35:58.000', 'user1', 5859 )

SELECT *
FROM
    ( SELECT *,
        -- Note integer division is used to round down to nearest 10 min interval
        DATEADD( MINUTE, DATEDIFF( MINUTE, 0, DT ) / 10 * 10, 0 ) AS TenMinuteIntervals,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY DATEADD( MINUTE, DATEDIFF( MINUTE, 0, DT ) / 10 * 10, 0 ) ORDER BY ID ) AS Duplicates
    FROM #Test ) AS Buckets
WHERE Duplicates = 1
```

Output:

```
 ID DT                  Username    ReadID  
 4  2016-06-08 15:35:58.000 user1   5859  
 1  2016-06-08 15:49:10.000 user1   5859
```

To return distinct reads you need to add `ReadID` column to the `PARTION BY` clause

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY ReadID, DATEADD( MINUTE, DATEDIFF( MINUTE, 0, DT ) / 10 * 10, 0 ) ORDER BY ID )
```

To return Aggregate results per ReadID you need to add `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT ReadID, COUNT( * ) AS Cnt
FROM
    ( SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY ReadID, DATEADD( MINUTE, DATEDIFF( MINUTE, 0, DT ) / 10 * 10, 0 ) ORDER BY ID ) AS Duplicates
    FROM #Test ) AS Buckets
WHERE Duplicates = 1
GROUP BY ReadID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY dte ASC) 
    AS rn 
    FROM #t1
) 

SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(id) > 0 
        THEN COUNT(id) 
    ELSE 
        1 
END AS cNt 
FROM #t1 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT 
    id 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t1.id id1
            , t2.id id2 
        FROM cte t1 
            LEFT JOIN 
            cte t2 
                ON t1.rn = t2.rn+1 
        WHERE 
            DATEDIFF(n, t2.dte,t1.dte) >= 10
    ) cte_usage
    UNPIVOT (
        id 
        FOR ids 
        IN (
            id1
            , id2
        )) AS up
)
```